# SAS : Summarise the data

Tags: csv, sas

I have a given data set:

```
Policy_Number,var1,var2,var3,Exposure
1,B,H,J,191
2,B,F,Unknown,174
3,C,Unknown,I,153
4,B,G,L,192
5,Unknown,E,Unknown,184
6,D,E,K,113
7,C,Unknown,I,140
8,A,H,I,133
9,C,F,I,194
10,Unknown,G,Unknown,105
11,B,H,L,172
12,A,Unknown,I,198
13,D,E,K,155
14,Unknown,G,K,177
15,B,H,Unknown,100
16,D,Unknown,J,176
17,B,E,I,112
18,Unknown,E,J,192
19,C,Unknown,K,146
20,C,G,Unknown,187
```

i want to convert the given data into following form by using PROC Means or Summary:

```
Variables   Levels   Tot_Exposures
  Var1        A           331
  Var1        B           941
  Var1        C           ...
  Var1        D           ...
  Var1     Unknown        ...   
  Var2        E           ...
  Var2        F           ...
  Var2        G           ...
  Var2        H           ...
  Var2     Unknown        ...   
  Var3        I           ...
  Var3        J           ...
  Var3        K           ...
  Var3        L           ...
  Var3     Unknown        ...
```

The Tot_Exposure returns the total exposure of each VariableName I want this summarized table. Please help me out here.

EDIT: i have tried the proc means method but i want it to carry out in one step. i did it in 3 steps. and got an output like the image.

[image: Output]

The code is like:

```
data try2;
infile 'complex.csv' dsd dlm = ',' FIRSTOBS = 2;
Length Policy_Number Var1 $ 10 Var2 $ 10 Var3 $ 10 Exposure 3;
input Policy_Number $ Var1 $ Var2 $ Var3 $ Exposure;
run;
proc sort data = try2;
by Exposure;
run;
proc means data = try2 SUM;
class Var1;
var exposure;
output out = want;
title ' Var1';
run;
proc means data = try2 SUM;
class Var2;
var exposure;
output out = want2;
title 'Var2';
run;
proc means data = try2 SUM;
class Var3;
var exposure;
output out = want3;
title 'Var3';
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all three variables summarized in one PROC SUMMARY step but the output is not exactly what you specify.  But that can achieved with a data step manipulation of the PROC SUMMARY output.  I used the MLF option on the CLASS statement to "convert" all the CLASS variable to character.  You don't have but it is useful as class variable can be either character of numeric.

```
data exp;
   infile cards dsd firstobs=2;
   input Policy_Number (var1-var3) ($) Exposure;
   cards;
Policy_Number,var1,var2,var3,Exposure
1,B,H,J,191
2,B,F,Unknown,174
3,C,Unknown,I,153
4,B,G,L,192
5,Unknown,E,Unknown,184
6,D,E,K,113
7,C,Unknown,I,140
8,A,H,I,133
9,C,F,I,194
10,Unknown,G,Unknown,105
11,B,H,L,172
12,A,Unknown,I,198
13,D,E,K,155
14,Unknown,G,K,177
15,B,H,Unknown,100
16,D,Unknown,J,176
17,B,E,I,112
18,Unknown,E,J,192
19,C,Unknown,K,146
20,C,G,Unknown,187
;;;;
   run;
proc summary data=exp descendtypes chartype;
   class var: / mlf;
   ways 1;
   freq Exposure;
   output out=test(rename=(_freq_=TotExposures));
   run;
data want;
   length variable $32 levels $8;
   set test;
   array v[*] var1-var3;
   drop var1-var3 i _type_;
   i = indexc(_type_,'1');
   variable = vname(v[i]);
   levels = v[i];
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: the data step of creating 'want' can't it be done without using arrays because the original dataset contains 350 variables of different names and i cannot initialize all the variables in the data step. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you're saying this can't work for 350 or more variables you are wrong.  You just need to know to work with "SAS Variable Lists".  It would be helpful if you mention all details instead of doling them out one by one.

Comment: basically the variable names can be anything. to be specific. The column names are AgeGroup, PolicyGroup, ClaimCosts, Claimreturns..... etc. and the levels are the values in the each group.

Comment: moreover the dataset consists of 4 million entries also. The main challenge is to get the dataset that you have created and then i have to subset it again to get desirable results.

Comment: @desmond.carros see my second answer that address all your concerns.  You will need to study this program to understand how it works as the techniques are new to you.

Comment: This method will work fine for 350 variables.  It takes only two "steps", one proc and one data step, no matter how many variables you select.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for carrying my old answer to a new post but dependent on your need for specifically proc summary my old method would calculate this for you.

If you swap out the last SQL part (I just added it in) to:

```
proc sql;
create table OUT as
  select VARIABLENAME
            , VARIABLEVALUE
            , sum(EXPOSURE)
    from
        GET_MAX
    group by 1,2
;quit;
```

Comment: well. to be true the original dataset may contain 45 million observations and 350 + variables with different variable names. I am afraid that the code may be inefficient. but let us assume that the Variables are named as Var1, Var2... but it may go upto 350+ records.

Comment: Please add the relevant info, such as num/var naming to main question.

Comment: @Reeza can you point out where the correction has to be made?

Comment: @desmond.carros this answer isn't correct given your new info. Please add new info to main question.

Comment: @Reeza actually AmitPatel gave this answer in reference to one of my old question. Though this query is still unsolved. you may give a try to this query. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will easily handle 350 variables 45 million records will take a while but PROC SUMMARY can easily handle that too.  The variable LEVELS needs to be defined with a length equal to or greater than the longest formatted value of all class variables.  You can ask how that is done in another question.

```
data exp;
   infile cards dsd firstobs=2;
   input Policy_Number (var1-var3) ($) Exposure;
   arbitraryname243 = rank(first(var1));
   arbitraryname4 = rantbl(123,.4);
   arbitraryname36 = rank(first(var3));
   cards;
Policy_Number,var1,var2,var3,Exposure
1,B,H,J,191
2,B,F,Unknown,174
3,C,Unknown,I,153
4,B,G,L,192
5,Unknown,E,Unknown,184
6,D,E,K,113
7,C,Unknown,I,140
8,A,H,I,133
9,C,F,I,194
10,Unknown,G,Unknown,105
11,B,H,L,172
12,A,Unknown,I,198
13,D,E,K,155
14,Unknown,G,K,177
15,B,H,Unknown,100
16,D,Unknown,J,176
17,B,E,I,112
18,Unknown,E,J,192
19,C,Unknown,K,146
20,C,G,Unknown,187
;;;;
   run;
proc transpose data=exp(obs=0 drop=policy_number exposure) out=varlist;
   var _all_;
   run;
Proc sql noprint; 
   select nliteral(_name_) into :classvars separated by ' ' from varlist;
   quit;
%put NOTE: &=classvars;

proc summary data=exp descendtypes chartype;
   class &classvars / mlf;
   ways 1;
   freq Exposure;
   output out=test(rename=(_freq_=TotExposures));
   run;
data want(keep=Variable levels totexposures);
   length variable $32 levels $8;
   set test;
   array v[*] &classvars;
   i = indexc(_type_,'1');
   variable = vname(v[i]);
   levels = v[i];
   run;
```